# Is it possible to create a filter using LastModifiedDate < LAST 30 MIN ??

Tags: standard-objects, filters

I have a custom object which is updated very often.

I need to create a lookup filter to avoid records where updated before 30 min ago.

I was trying something like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to use relative date filter criteria down to the minutes.  The smallest increment is in days:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US

You could create a formula field on the record that looked something like this

```
IF( ( NOW()*24*60 - LastModifiedDate*24*60 ) < 30, 'True','False')
```

And then you can just check for True or False in your report criteria.  I think I have my minutes calculation correct, it's worth double checking.

Answer (score 3):

Create a hidden formula field on the target object, called something like "30 Mins Ago", with formula `NOW() - 0.020833333`.

Then add filter criteria of Last Modified Date less than Field: 30 Mins Ago.

Comment: Is this new, the ability to compare against another field? If so, very handy.

Comment: Yeah, not sure which release it was added in but I think it was fairly recent. It's useful but it could still be better (for instance, can't use a text field as a source field in a lookup filter which is annoying).